# When using しか, which part do we have to negate?

Tags: grammar, negation, particle-しか

I want to say "Mathematics is the only thing I trust." using しか. But I am not sure which part I have to negate.

Which one is the correct one? A or B?

> A: 数学しか信頼できるものじゃない。
>
> B: 数学しか信頼でないものだ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your sentences are unnatural. 数学しか信頼できない is natural.

Comment: How about  「数学しか信頼することが出来ない。」or  「数学を信頼することしか出来ない。」?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian. Both are fine, asked which to choose, I will give you a coin.

Comment: 数学しか信頼することが出来ない is natural but I think 数学を信頼することしか出来ない may be a bit different meaning from your questions sentence. It is translated as "What I can do is only to trust Mathematics.